# Open Browser in Powershell just stopped working

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell

I've been creating Windows Powershell scripts to automate Web UI Testing for the past couple of weeks. They have all worked fine until today I ran them and got a million exceptions. I tried to manually create an InternetExplorer object:

```
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
```

And I get this error:

```
New-Object : Creating an instance of the COM component with CLSID {0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} from the IClassFactory failed due to the following error: 800704a6.
At line:1 char:17 + $ie = new-object  <<<< -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
```

This is the exact same code I have been using over and over to run InternetExplorer. Why has it suddenly stopped working and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to restart windows? According to some posts the problem indicates that there is pending shutdown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Weird, that error message corresponds to this:

> A system shutdown has already been
>   scheduled. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x800704A6)

Did you update IE or otherwise install something requiring a machine reboot?

Comment: Not that I know of. But I suppose a reboot couldn't hurt. I will be back in a sec

Comment: Yea that worked. I feel stupid that I didn't think to restart at all. But my computer has barely been on and I haven't used IE. Thanks!