# Excel VBA force shutdown IE

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

I am currently using the following sub to close my IE after automating:

```
Public Sub CloseIE()
    Dim Shell As Object
    Dim IE As Object

    Set Shell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")

    For Each IE In Shell.Windows
        If TypeName(IE.Document) = "HTMLDocument" Then
            IE.Quit
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This works great but the problem occurs when I try to run the IE code again, I get the following:

Run-time error '-2147023706 (800704a6)':

Automation error

A system shutdown has already been scheduled.

After 20 secs, I can re-run the code. Is there any way of "force closing" IE so that I can run the code again directly after without the error?

EDIT:

Heres the code that initiates IE:

```
Sub testSub()

    Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, strCode As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True

      IE.Navigate "website name"

        Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set Doc = IE.Document 

       CODE HERE

       CloseIE

End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps you should show the code where you instantiate IE and create that object. It seems that would be a better place to resolve this problem.  First, by assigning that object to a variable, and then by using that object's `.Quit` method and setting the object variable to `Nothing`.  The current approach is not ideal.

Comment: You should use the IE object directly from when it has been instantiated. This problem is down to poor design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your main sub to `Quit` the IE application, and then set the object variable to `Nothing`:

```
Sub testSub()

    Dim IE As Object, Doc As Object, strCode As String

    Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    IE.Visible = True

      IE.Navigate "website name"

        Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        Set Doc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
        Set Doc = IE.Document 

       '### CODE HERE

       IE.Quit
       Set IE = Nothing

End Sub
```

You will not need the `CloseIE` procedure anymore.

Comment: Thanks, this helped as I think it halved the time I got the error but I still got the error. I think I know why and its because I forgot to mention I have two tabs in IE to close, your code only seems to close one. Could you please tell me how to close both tabs?

Comment: `IE` is the application object, the `Quit` method should close the entire application, is that not what you're experiencing?

Comment: It closes the IE ok but I still get the error when I try to run another IE straight after

Comment: Yes at: Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

Comment: Hmmm. Doesn't sound like it's related to the method of closing the IE then, something else must be causing the error. Have you tried googling for that error message?  Alternatively  (it's more complicated but could avoid the IE error) you could use an xmlhttprequest instead of IE. Unless you *need* to use IE...

Comment: I found this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/189618
I dont really need IE, all I am trying to do is go online and fill out some <input> box's on a browser. Is there any way I can make a simple modification to my code to make this work without the error? The code works fine, its just when its ran multiple times it has a sort of "cooldown time" after each run.

Comment: Probably not a simple method, I haven't had time too look at the error specifically although the link you posted is NOT about IE. I think xmlhttprequest would be the way to go but without seeing the rest of your code I don't know if that would be simple or difficult to implement.

Comment: [This](https://www.mjtnet.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7538) is a similar problem, and I would ask the same questions: "*Why not just navigate the page again or refresh. i.e. loop to the navigate not the create. Why close IE if you are going to use it again?*"

Comment: [Another similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542666/open-browser-in-powershell-just-stopped-working) suggests that maybe you need to reboot? If you reboot, does the problem persist?

Answer (score 2):

I used a simple procedure to create an `InternetExplorer` object, navigate, then close it using `IE.Quit` and `Set IE = Nothing`.

Apparently after closing, the internet was still running in the background for about another minute (I noticed it using task manager, background processes). I went into Internet Explorer options and unclicked “*delete browsing history on exit*”.

That fixed my issue. I am not sure why IE takes that long to clear the history and I’m not sure if there is a workaround but it is the only viable option for me thus far.