# IE fast automation

Tags: regex, vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am currently trying to web scrape some exchange rates from a website called [X-Rates](http://www.x-rates.com/), using VBA. My current problem is that it just takes too long to run. I have narrowed it down to the *Do Events* of my IE object.

My question: **Is there a better way of doing this (maybe some better efficiency of code), or my logic is just flawed?**

Here's what the code does:

1 - Loop for each country (1-9 = offsetCurr);

2- Convert to exchange rate and preserve value on cell

```
    'Define variables
    Dim strElm     As String
    Dim i          As Integer
    Dim ie         As InternetExplorer
    Dim period     As Variant
    Dim offsetCurr As Integer
    Dim offsetDesc As String

    'Define period
    period = Application.InputBox("What's the year and period?", "Period", , , , , 2)

    'Define start row
    i = 2

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    For offsetCurr = 1 To 9

        If offsetCurr = 1 Then

            'ARS to EURO
            Set ie = New InternetExplorer
            offsetDesc = "ARS"
            Cells(i, 1).Value = period
            Cells(i, 2).Value = offsetDesc
            ie.navigate "http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=ARS&to=EUR&amount=1"

            Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop

            d = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ccOutputRslt")(0).innerText
            strElm = d
            Cells(i, 3).Value = strElm

            ie.Quit
            Set ie = Nothing

            'ARS to USD
            Set ie = New InternetExplorer
            ie.navigate "http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=ARS&to=USD&amount=1"

            Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop

            d = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ccOutputRslt")(0).innerText
            strElm = d
            Cells(i, 4).Value = strElm

            'Quit IE for automation purposes
            ie.Quit
            Set ie = Nothing

            'ARS to GBP
            Set ie = New InternetExplorer
            ie.navigate "http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=ARS&to=GBP&amount=1"

            Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
                DoEvents
            Loop

            d = ie.document.getElementsByClassName("ccOutputRslt")(0).innerText
            strElm = d
            Cells(i, 5).Value = strElm

            ie.Quit
            Set ie = Nothing

        End If

ErrHandler:

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Msg = "Error #" & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " & Err.Source & "." & Chr(13) & "Error description: " & Err.Description
        MsgBox Msg, , "Error", Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
        Exit Sub
    End If

End Sub
```

I know it's a significant amount of code, if needed I can edit the question to make it simpler.

Comment: I've found on this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626253/excel-vba-force-shutdown-ie) that one workaround might be “deleting browsing history on exit”. Will try to implement

Comment: So you're saying the DoEvents portion is slow? If you're waiting on DoEvents than your waiting on the browser not VBA. You could also open 3 separate browsers so you don't have to keep navigating back forth from a single browser 9 times.

Comment: If you have working code which merely needs improvements then you're probably in the wrong place with this post. [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is where they handle existing / working code and do their best to improve it in terms of speed, security, sustainability, and longevity. Give it a try. They're good!

Comment: Have you tried XHR [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30856280/2165759) instead of IE?

Comment: @omegastripes No I did not. Will try !! Thanks!

Comment: @Charlie I will try with XMLHTTP and see if they're any changes in speed

Comment: @Ralph Thanks for the sugestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example showing how to retrieve rates via XHR:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub TestGetRate()

    Dim sCrcy As Variant

    For Each sCrcy In Array("EUR", "USD", "GBP")
        Debug.Print GetRate("ARS", sCrcy)
    Next

End Sub

Function GetRate(sFromCrcy, sToCrcy)

    Dim sUrl, sContent

    sUrl = "http://www.x-rates.com/calculator/?from=" & sFromCrcy & "&to=" & sToCrcy & "&amount=1"
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHttp")
        .Open "GET", sUrl, False
        .send
        sContent = .ResponseText
    End With
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "<span class=""ccOutputRslt"">(.*?)<span class=""ccOutputTrail"">(.*?)</span><span class=""ccOutputCode"">(.*?)</span></span>"
        With .Execute(sContent).Item(0)
            GetRate = .SubMatches(0) & .SubMatches(1) & .SubMatches(2)
        End With
    End With

End Function
```

Output is as follows for me:

> 0.061688 EUR
>   0.070373 USD
>   0.048865 GBP

Comment: @svacxpython you can find info on XMLHTTPRequest methods and properties on MSDN and even Wikipedia, what you actually need is some practice with real websites. Try Chrome - Developer Tools (F12) - Network tab, make some actions on the webpage and find appeared XHR, examine headers, query parameters and data. Mostly web scraping implies some reverse engineering and web page structure review.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are starting a new instance of IE and closing it completely for each of the 9 loops.  Try starting IE once at beginning, then loop through each currency type, then quit IE.

Comment: Just did that, but the browser keeps stalling ! Do you recommend using other browser?