# How do i solve this "Run-Time Error '-2147023706 (800704a6)"?

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

i have a big problem with this code:

```
Sub EstrazDati_A_ieri()

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate Range("D2")

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In output
    If link.innerHTML = "Main" Then
        Range("D3").Value2 = link
    End If

Next
IE.Quit

End Sub
```

The code is correct and it works, but sometimes after a continuous use of itself a Windows box appear with a Run-Time Error on this line:

```
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
```

I have already tested several solutions found on the internet but i couldn't fix it.

p.s. I'm an Italian boy sorry for the bad English :)

Comment: How often is this run, could it be an issue with IE itself, long script, messagebox showing or something.  Do task manager, check on the IE being still active.  Perhaps, try grabbing an open IE first, using error trapping to create one, if one isn't open?  Try a doevnts after the quit

Comment: Does `Set IE = New InternetExplorerMedium` work? or maybe `Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")`?  Also, when you mean after continuous use, do you mean you run the sub once, and it loops a lot, and gives an error? Or it runs once, all the way through, and when you run it again it'll error?

Comment: If you are running this code at high frequency, you might want to cache the IE object and not create one every time. If I remember well the InternetExplorer object takes time to be destroyed after the Quit and may keep using resources even after the end of the function, blocking next creations.

Comment: Is that the correct error code? My headers say that's `ERROR_SHUTDOWN_IS_SCHEDULED`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA force shutdown IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626253/excel-vba-force-shutdown-ie)

Comment: You need to add `Set IE = Nothing` after `IE.Quit`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I click every two seconds on various buttons which are linked these macro, always the same code, but with different target cells, now you can see "D2" and "D3", another same code with "D4" and "D5" and so on... And after some click the error come out.

Comment: @BruceWayne No bruce just done, the first solution open a InternetExplorer window that i would like to remain closed and it gave me another kind of error: "Class doesn't support Automation (Error 430)", on this line: "Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE". The second solution gave me the same error of the question.

Comment: @VincentG Yeah, i've read the same thing on internet and in fact after a few seconds or minutes the code back to work, but i need to use it 12 times in a span of a few seconds. After that i can also wait several minutes because i have to analyze the data extracted on my Excel document, the problem is only those 12 clicks.

Comment: @RobinMackenzie yeah Robin the error is the same, but if i add `Set IE = Nothing` the error remain :(

Comment: You can cache the IE object instead of destroying it and creating a new one each time.

Comment: Look at using `CreateObject` and `GetObject` with some error trapping, so you only open & close 1 instance of IE, just navigate/refresh each time, so the 1st time will take a shade longer, the other 11 will be quicker.

Comment: @VincentG How can i do this? if i close and open again the excel file i can't use the marco the error still there :(

Comment: Since there is no `Dim IE ...` in your code I think it is defined as a global variable somewhere? If so just check for `Nothing` and create a new instance only if needed. `If IE is Nothing Then Set IE = New InternetExplorer`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Ehi, i've put  `Set IE = Nothing` after `IE.Quit` only in the 1/12 of my macro code and it's seem to work, now I will do other tests to see if the problem is really solved. Unfortunately i can not make many consecutive tests because excel crash constantly.

Comment: Your loop is not checking for IE.Busy, Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE and not ie.busy you could try also.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Ok, but the crash is due to the fact that the links generated by the macro executions are taken and used by Dynamic Web Query and when the and when queries calculate Excel crash

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Unfortunately the problem persists, 2 clicks are ok but on the 3rd there is the problem, always on the 3rd :(

Comment: do you think is so important here to IE like a global variable? The macro run also without

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution on the internet and **it works** by the moment, do you think is it right?

```
Sub EstrazDati_A_ieri()
On Error Resume Next

Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object

Set IE = New InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate Range("D2")

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In output
    If link.innerHTML = "Main" Then
        Range("D3").Value2 = link
    End If

Next
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT :** Now i've tried in this way

```
Sub EstrazDati_A_ieri()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate Range("D2")

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In output
    If link.innerHTML = "Main" Then
        Range("D3").Value2 = link
    End If

Next
IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

But after the eighth run of these macro's ERROR :(

Comment: x_X with that modification there aren't errors but the macro's don't respond

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub EstrazDati_A_ieri()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As HTMLDocument
Dim output As Object

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate Range("D2")

Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set doc = IE.document
Set output = doc.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each link In output
    If link.innerHTML = "Main" Then
        Range("D3").Value2 = link
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

**Ok Guys! in this way no error.** The problem is just that i would not open up a new web page every time but i would used the same, because i have to run this macro repeatedly for 12 times.
How can i modify this line of code?

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
```